# Application becomes unresponsive when gdb is attached, or Qt runs in debugging mode

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, gdb

I am in Ubuntu 16.10. I think I have a problem with my gdb. 
It happens that when I try to attach a gdb from terminal to my running application, my application freezes.

Also, using Qt creator, when I run my application in the release mode, it builds just fine but when I run it in the debug mode, a new window (representing my running application) opens up, but already freezes in a sad black unresponsive window.

Does anybody have an idea why the application becomes already unresponsive when running the application in the debugging mode?
Has it have something to do with gdb, or is it a Qt problem alone?

Comment: The first is not a problem. If you continue application after attaching, it should unfreeze.

Comment: I tried to wait a little, and still if I click on my frozen black unresponsive application, nothing happens.. it stays black. It doesn't unfreeze. Should I wait more than 2 minutes? Also, when I quit the terminal, the application comes back active.

Comment: I think what @ks1322 is saying is that after gdb attaches it will halt the process.  You then need to issue the `continue` command at the gdb prompt to resume execution.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this.

Comment: And you both are right, indeed :D